# Truncate Text using sql (all text after a DIV tag)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have almost 4k rows in my database (having description of product).

There is a DIV tag inside all rows

`<div id="myiol" class="educt">`

And some random text and tags after this DIV. I want to truncate everything in all rows after this DIV (including this DIV)

I have tried REPLACE but i have to make around 50-60 combinations.

Can someone please advise and help how to do it.

Comment: What version of MySQL? If you're using 8.x, you can use `REPLACE_REGEXP()`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '<div id="myiol" class="educt">', 1)
WHERE LOCATE('<div id="myiol" class="educt">', column)
```

If the tag itself must be stored then

```
UPDATE table
SET column = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '<div id="myiol" class="educt">', 1), '<div id="myiol" class="educt">')
WHERE LOCATE('<div id="myiol" class="educt">', column)
```

Alternatively

```
UPDATE table
SET column = LEFT(column, LOCATE('<div id="myiol" class="educt">', column) - 1)
WHERE LOCATE('<div id="myiol" class="educt">', column)
```

or

```
UPDATE table
SET column = LEFT(column, LOCATE('<div id="myiol" class="educt">', column) + LENGTH('<div id="myiol" class="educt">') - 1)
WHERE LOCATE('<div id="myiol" class="educt">', column)
```